# SSIS control flow 2 out of 3

Tags: ssis, control-flow

I have a package where I want to have task A always run and B or C run (but not both) and I want them to run concurrently before they (all three) go to the next task. So I know how to set the constraints so that either B or C succeeds but adding in A is a problem. In the Multiple Constraints part of the editor I need another option to point to the task (A) that is AND while the other two tasks are OR.

Anybody know a way to work around that?

Comment: Put the B and C in a Sequence Container. I generally like to use an empty Script Task as the parent but you could do the same thing with Expressions on the Disabled property for them. I find this cleaner [Picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EEDc2.png)

Comment: I may implement that but it is still rather ugly.

Comment: What would a non-ugly solution look like?

Comment: A non-ugly solution would come from Microsoft in the form of another option. I'm not sure there is a non-ugly work around.

Comment: No matter how I try, I'll never be able to give you something. Something that I just haven't got.